# Empty result in my response to front-end, but in console is returning OK

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, asynchronous, backend

So, I have a REST API, and I want to return some data to my front-end.

So I have this code:

```js
.then(async result => {
            // return result.rows

            return result.rows.map(async res1 => {
                res1.datasProc = [];
                const getDatt = await getDatasProcedimentos(res1.GUIA_SENHA);
                res1.datasProc.push(...getDatt);
                console.log(res1);
                return res1;
            })
        })
```

In the line 2 `return result.rows`, its ok. But I want to add some data at this object with map method. This data come from line 6 (SQL query). I already test the query function and its working fine. At line 8, my res1 Object, contain all the data that I want, but the result is empty.

My console.log(res1)

```js
{
  NM_PESSOA_FISICA: 'name of someone',
  NR_CPF: 'document of someone',
  GUIA_SENHA: 'id of company',
  PROCEDIMENTO: 'procedure of someone in company',
  DATA: 'timestamp',
  DS_PROCEDIMENTO: 'description of procedure',
  datasProc: [
    { 'timestamp1' },
    { 'timestamp2' },
    { 'timestamp3' }
  ]
} ... and so on
```

My response to front-end (Prompt by insomnia using the endpoint)

```js
result = [
{},
{},
{},
{},
{},
{},
// ... and so on
]
```

I've tried in another ways, like assign the map result into variable and returning that, but the asynchronous block is returning first and after doing the map.

Edit 1: My controller to send the data is in a try-catch block:

```js
try {
            const guiasPorPeriodo = await guiaDAO.getGuiasPorPeriodo(data_filtro_inicial, data_filtro_final, idClinic);

            if (guiasPorPeriodo) {
                return res.json({
                    "resultado": guiasPorPeriodo,
                    "status": "success",
                    "message": "enviado com sucesso"
                });
            } else {
                throw new Error('Ocorreu algum erro ao consultar as guias neste período.')
            }

        } catch (err) {
            return res.status(400).json({
                "status": "fail",
                "error message": `${err.name}: ${err.message}`
            });
        }
```

language: pt-BR

Comment: You haven't provided the code that actually *sends* data to the front end, and that's probably where your problem is. What does that look like? The code here just shows how you're manipulating data, but we also need to see how you're sending it in your express route or however.

Comment: Sorry about that @user3781737, i edited the post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This statement:

```js
return result.rows.map(async res1 => {
```

will return an array of Promises, not resulting objects. To make sure your async function would return array of actual results I would try this:

```js
.then(result => {
            // return result.rows

            return Promise.all(result.rows.map(async res1 => {
                res1.datasProc = [];
                const getDatt = await getDatasProcedimentos(res1.GUIA_SENHA);
                res1.datasProc.push(...getDatt);
                console.log(res1);
                return res1;
            }))
        })
```

The mapper function is declared as async so technically it returns a promise.
And a function which is not declared as async but returns a Promise still can be called with **await**.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is your map with async/await. A function with await will return a promise, and you need to wait for the promise to get resolved. Try with Promise.all, that should wait until all your promises are resolved.

```
.then(async result => {
            // return result.rows

            return Promise.all(result.rows.map(async res1 => {
                res1.datasProc = [];
                const getDatt = await getDatasProcedimentos(res1.GUIA_SENHA);
                res1.datasProc.push(...getDatt);
                console.log(res1);
                return res1;
            }))
        })
```

Another way could be to use a for loop. That works better with async/await.